# Treat the same msgid localized in different location separately via pyBabel

Tags: python, gettext

I am trying to translate my application using pyBabel. The problem is with extracting message ids. pyBabel is merging the same msgid in `.pot` file. This is fine only for English translation (default).

```
#: file.py:1
#: file.py:2
msgid "foo"
msgstr ""
```

Other localization requires different translation e.g.:

- "foo" in line no. 1 of file.py is translated to "bar"
- "foo" in line no. 2 of file.py is translated to "baz"

Is it possible to enforce splitting same msgid according to localization to achieve automatically:

```
#: file.py:1
msgid "foo"
msgstr ""

#: file.py:2
msgid "foo"
msgstr ""
```

I am aware, that I can just use different `msgid` in line no. 1 and line no. 2, but this approach will enforce to prepare custom `.po` with the same msg_str:

locale\en\LC_MESSAGES\file.po

```
#: file.py:1
msgid "foo_1"
msgstr "foo"

#: file.py:2
msgid "foo_2"
msgstr "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what message contexts are made for. Instead of `_(MSGID)` or `gettext(MSGID)` you have to use `pgettext(CONTEXT, MSGID)`:

```py
import gettext

print(gettext.pgettext('bar context', 'foo'))
print(gettext.pgettext('baz context', 'baz'))
```

This is the output for English

```
$ python file.py
foo
foo
```

And extracting translatable strings from `file.py` should result in a `.po` file like the following:

```
#: file.py:1
msgctxt "bar context"
msgid "foo"
msgstr ""

#: file.py:2
msgctxt "baz context"
msgid "foo"
msgstr ""
```

The translator can now give two distinct translations for the string "foo" because the occurrences are distinguishable by the message context.